# OpenVPN Stuck on Connecting

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, vpn, openvpn

I installed OpenVPN, `OpenVPN-2.5.1-I601-amd64.msi`, on a `Windows 10 Pro x64` PC.

The server is a Netgear R6230 router, which I configured for DDNS and VPN.

Problem:
My connection attempt is stuck on "Connecting"
[image: OpenVPN Connection - Connecting]

Here is the log:

```
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_pin_cache_period = -1
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_id = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pkcs11_id_management = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   server_network = 0.0.0.0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   server_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   server_network_ipv6 = ::
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   server_netbits_ipv6 = 0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   server_bridge_ip = 0.0.0.0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   server_bridge_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   server_bridge_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   server_bridge_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   ifconfig_pool_defined = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   ifconfig_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   ifconfig_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   ifconfig_pool_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   ifconfig_pool_persist_filename = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   ifconfig_pool_persist_refresh_freq = 600
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_defined = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_base = ::
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_netbits = 0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   n_bcast_buf = 256
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   tcp_queue_limit = 64
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   real_hash_size = 256
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   virtual_hash_size = 256
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   client_connect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   learn_address_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   client_disconnect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   client_config_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   ccd_exclusive = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   tmp_dir = 'C:\Users\tammara\AppData\Local\Temp\'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   push_ifconfig_defined = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   push_ifconfig_local = 0.0.0.0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   push_ifconfig_remote_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   push_ifconfig_ipv6_defined = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   push_ifconfig_ipv6_local = ::/0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   push_ifconfig_ipv6_remote = ::
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   enable_c2c = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   duplicate_cn = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   cf_max = 0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   cf_per = 0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   max_clients = 1024
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   max_routes_per_client = 256
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   auth_user_pass_verify_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   auth_user_pass_verify_script_via_file = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   auth_token_generate = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   auth_token_lifetime = 0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   auth_token_secret_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   vlan_tagging = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   vlan_accept = all
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   vlan_pvid = 1
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   client = ENABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   pull = ENABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   auth_user_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   show_net_up = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   route_method = 3
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   block_outside_dns = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   ip_win32_defined = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   ip_win32_type = 3
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   dhcp_masq_offset = 0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   dhcp_lease_time = 31536000
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   tap_sleep = 0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   dhcp_options = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   dhcp_renew = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   dhcp_pre_release = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   domain = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   netbios_scope = '[UNDEF]'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   netbios_node_type = 0
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021   disable_nbt = DISABLED
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021 OpenVPN 2.5.1 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Feb 24 2021
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021 Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater) 64bit
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021, LZO 2.10
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Sun Mar 28 16:13:45 2021 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 5'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 LZO compression initializing
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1654 D:1212 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1616973226,RESOLVE,,,,,,
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1654 D:1450 EF:122 EB:411 ET:32 EL:3 ]
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1590,tun-mtu 1532,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1590,tun-mtu 1532,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 UDP link local: (not bound)
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974
Sun Mar 28 16:13:46 2021 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1616973226,WAIT,,,,,,
```

As you can see there are not to many options. I downloaded the config file, which was innocent enough.

[image: Netgear Router VPN]

Here is the config file, which I downloaded. I changed the generic name to a unique name.

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
dev-node NETGEAR-VPN
remote <DDNSName> 12974
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
**key-direction 1**
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca<name>.crt
cert client<name>.crt
key client<name>.key
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 5
```

Thoughts?

**Update for Answer 1**

I  added the missing key-direction, see updated script above, with ** on both sides for direction.

The log looks the same. Here are the last few lines.

```
Sun Mar 28 19:01:30 2021 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address:     [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974
Sun Mar 28 19:01:30 2021 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Sun Mar 28 19:01:30 2021 UDP link local: (not bound)
Sun Mar 28 19:01:30 2021 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]172.88.131.44:12974
Sun Mar 28 19:01:30 2021 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1616983290,WAIT,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard openvpn configuration includes an item, key-direction, which controls which side begins the key negotiation (which is where your connection is getting stuck). I don't see this in your client config file.

Try adding the following to your client config file:

`key-direction 1`

It can be placed anywhere after the 'client' tag. (as noted in the comments, this tag might not help.)

Additionally, there might be a firewall in the way.  The R6230 instructions do not point out that ports 12973/upd and 12974/udp (vanilla configuration), or whatever ports you decided to use, must be forwarded through your firewall to the R6230 for the OpenVPN to work.

Addition

Comment: I added the line, see the updated script above, restarted OpenVPN, and attempted to connect. Same problem. I added the last few lines of the log. To me, the hang looks to be in the same spot.

Comment: The most likely issue is that there is a firewall in the way.  I assume your R6230 is connected to a (DSL|Cable) modem.  Did you configure the modem's firewall to forward ports 12973/upd and 12974/udp to your R6230?

Comment: My apologies for the delay, but I was only able to get back to the computer yesterday. The problem was the firewall indeed. I should have mentioned the configuration. I have a Spectrum cable router coming in from the outside. My NetGear R6230 router connects to the Spectrum router, so there is indeed the firewall. I am not sure that the `key-direction 1` addition would have made any difference. The real answer is the firewall, but I will mark your answer as valid. Thank you.